# Restar fechas en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

mi duda es que tengo esta sintaxis que insertare en un procedimiento almacenado

```
  OPEN curDocs;
 SET @fNotificacion = getdate();
```

pero quiero poner un if entre medio , y decirle que si fecha de notificación es igual a 1 de cada mes , restarle una fecha , de modo que si hoy es 01-04-2019 me reste y me quede como 31-03-2019 , si no entra al getdate(), me han dicho que datediff es la manera de usarlo pero no entiendo bien como hacerlos

Comment: No entiendo qué quieres decir con esto, sobre todo al final: _«de modo que si hoy es 01-04-2019 me reste y me quede como 31-03-2019 , si no entra al getdate()»_

Comment: Quiero decir que IF @fNotificacion = primer dia del mes restale un dia ELSE obtiene el dia de hoy , solo necesito que entre a ese if los primeros dias de cada mes , los demas siempre entrara al dia de hoy con el getdate

Answer (score 1):

Puedes poner esa condición en la declaración de la variable, por ejemplo:

```
SET @fNotificacion = IF(DAY(NOW())=1, NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY ,NOW());
```

Así `@fNotificacion` tendrá el valor de la fecha actual, pero si es el primer día del mes, tendrá el valor del día anterior.

#### Prueba

```
SELECT @fNotificacion;
```

**Salida:**

```
@fNotificacion
--------------------
2019-03-31 15:25:59
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo, que estas hablando de `SQL-Server` por el `getdate()`

```
DECLARE @fNotificacion DATETIME

SET @fNotificacion = getdate()

SET @fNotificacion = CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,@fNotificacion) = 1 
                          THEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, @fNotificacion)
                          ELSE @fNotificacion 
                     END
```

Detalle

- Usamos la clausula `CASE WHEN <condicion> THEN <valor> ELSE <valor> END` para modificar el valor a asignar en `@fNotificacion`
- Importante, en primer lugar establecemos el valor mediante `SET @fNotificacion = getdate()`, esto es por que `getdate()` es una rutina no determinística, es decir cada vez que la ejecutes te retornará un valor distinto.